# Access CakePHP database connection

Tags: php, cakephp, database-connection

I'm looking for a way to access the database object CakePHP uses to make its calls to the database.

I have a class I wrote outside of CakePHP that uses the database. Instead of opening its own connection, I thought it would be nice to just use one that may already be open.

I have CakePHP set up to use MySQLi and the class I built uses MySQLi as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use DboSource Class for accessing Database and making database calls.
 [DboSource Class API doc](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DboSource.html)

`getConnection`

[Get the underlying connection object.](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-ConnectionManager.html#__getConnectionObject)

Comment: Hello, Thanks, but I want the connection itself without going through another layer.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I thought it would be a callable object, not a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$db= &ConnectionManager::getDataSource('datasourceName'); // as defined in DATABASE.php
```